# What is the purpose of the ACC_SUPER access flag on Java Class files?

Tags: java, class, jvm, opcode

The `invokespecial` JVM instruction is used for calling initialisation methods (`<init>`) when creating new objects. The description of the instruction suggests (but doesn't clarify) that the decision on whether to call the constructor of a superclass or a constructor of the current class depends on the state of the `ACC_SUPER` flag set within the `class` file.

From the Sun JVM Specification:

> Next, the resolved method is selected for invocation unless all of the following conditions are true:
>
> - The ACC_SUPER flag (see Table 4.1, "Class access and property modifiers") is set for the current class.

-- [Source](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc6.html#invokespecial) (`invokespecial` opcode definition)

> The setting of the ACC_SUPER flag indicates which of two alternative semantics for its invokespecial instruction the Java virtual machine is to express; the ACC_SUPER flag exists for backward compatibility for code compiled by Sun's older compilers for the Java programming language. All new implementations of the Java virtual machine should implement the semantics for invokespecial documented in this specification. All new compilers to the instruction set of the Java virtual machine should set the ACC_SUPER flag. Sun's older compilers generated ClassFile flags with ACC_SUPER unset. Sun's older Java virtual machine implementations ignore the flag if it is set.

-- [Source](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html) (`ClassFile` format)

The definition states that the flag is for backward compatibility with old compilers. However it goes on to contradict with `Sun's older Java virtual machine implementations ignore the flag if it is set.`

Is the flag still used with the `invokespecial` opcode? From what I can tell, it seems to hold no purpose and I can't find a resource to suggest it ever did.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but to understand why the flag is used I think you also need to understand what the flag meant under the JVM version 1 spec - see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/first_edition/html/Instructions2.doc7.html#invokespecial

Comment: Side by side, I can't see any difference.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

ACC_SUPER was introduced to correct a problem with the invocation of super methods. The ACC_SUPER flag marks a class as compiled for the changed semantics of the opcode 183 instruction. It's purpose is similar to that of the class file version number as it allows the JVM to detect whether a class was compiled for the older or newer semantics of that instruction. Java 1.0.2 did not set and ignored ACC_SUPER while Java 1.1 and later always sets ACC_SUPER.

Before Java 1.1 the byte code instruction with opcode 183 that is now called `invokespecial` was called `invokenonvirtual` and had a partially different specification. It was used whenever instance methods had to be invoked without a virtual method lookup. This was the case for private methods, instance initializers (constructors) and to implement method invocations on `super`. But the latter case caused problems with evolving class libraries.

A method reference in byte code (`CONSTANT_Methodref_info`) not only defines the name and the argument and return types of a method but also the class to which it belongs. Opcode 183 gets such a method reference parameter and was meant to directly invoke the referenced method from the specified class without further lookups. In the case of invocations on `super` it was the compilers responsibility to resolve the closest super class that implements this method and generate a reference to it into the byte code.

Since Java 1.1 it was changed to essentially ignore the class referenced in `CONSTANT_Methodref_info` and to instead do the lookup for the closest super method with the given method name and signature in the JVM. This is usually done now when the class gets loaded or right before the instruction is executed or JIT compiled the first time.

Here is an example why this change was neccessary. In Java 1.0.2 the AWT classes `Container` and `Component` were defined this way:

```
class Component
{
    public void paint( Graphics g ) {}
}

class Container extends Component
{
    // inherits paint from Component but doesn't override it
}
```

In Java 1.1 the class `Container` was changed to have its own implementation of `paint`:

```
class Container extends Component
{
    public void paint( Graphics g ) {/*...*/}
}
```

Now when you had a direct or indirect subclass of `Container` that made a call on `super.paint(g)` and compiled it for 1.0.2 it generated a `invokenonvirtual` instruction for `Component.paint` since this was the first parent that had this method. But if you used this compiled class on a JVM that also had `Container.paint` it would still have called `Component.paint` which is not what you would expect.

On the other hand, when you compiled the class for 1.1 and executed it on a 1.0.2 JVM it would throw a AbstractMethodError or more likely for VMs of that era simply crash. To avoid the crash you had to write `((Component)super).paint(g)` and compile it with a 1.1 compiler to get the desired behaviour in either VM. This would set ACC_SUPER but still generate the instruction to call `Component.paint`. A 1.0.2 VM would ignore ACC_SUPER and go straight to invoke `Component.paint` which is fine while a 1.1 VM would find ACC_SUPER set and thus do the lookup itself which would make it invoke `Container.paint` even though the byte code method reference was `Component.paint`.

You can find more about this in [this old post on the ikvm.net weblog](https://web.archive.org/web/20210518044444/weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=99fcff6c-8ab7-4358-9467-ddf71dd20acd).

Comment: Interesting post. So all compilers after 1.1 set the flag, making the JVM check the `super` hierarchy when resolving methods? Is that done instead of using the `objectref` popped from the stack?

Comment: This is a very good answer. I now understand how `invokespecial` works with the flag. But why did they not just deprecate the old method?

Comment: As of Java 7u13 security update the absence of the ACC_SUPER flag is no longer honored by the JVM. This is because of the issue described here: http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=23cced47-ccdb-460d-acc9-ce16154ab6a5

Answer (score 0):

The `ACC_SUPER` flag has not done anything since Java 8.

Per [JEP draft: Better-defined JVM class file validation](https://openjdk.org/jeps/8267650):

> The `ACC_SUPER` flag, which has no effect since Java 8, will no longer be specified.

While I haven't found a single concise easily-linkable authoritative source, it seems that the functionality was removed prior to Java 8, in a Java 7 security update.